# replace negative values with NA for all columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose my data looks something like this (with many more columns)

```
set.seed(112116)
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(c(LETTERS, -1:-10), 100, replace = T),
                 x2 = sample(c(letters, -1:-10), 100, replace = T),
                 x3 = sample(c(1:30, -1:-10), 100, replace = T))
```

I want to replace all negative numbers with NA. I can do it one by one like this:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(x1 = replace(x1, which(x1<0), NA),
              x2 = replace(x2, which(x2<0), NA),
              x3 = replace(x3, which(x3<0), NA))
```

But i'm hoping that there is a way of doing this for all columns in my data

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with `mutate_each`

```
df %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., .<0, NA)))
```

---

Or in the newer version  of `dplyr` version >= 1.00

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(),  ~ case_when(.x >=0 ~ .x)))
```

Comment: Since `mutate_each` is deprecated (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090654/r-mutate-each-function-is-deprecated), `mutate_all` will do the trick.

Comment: To elaborate, here are two solutions that work with the current version of `dplyr`: `df |> mutate_all(list(~ replace(., . < 0, NA)))` or `df |> mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . < 0, NA)))`. The latter is more flexible if you only want to replace in specific columns.